# OpenGL - Display List

Tags: opengl

If I need to change the opacity of an object that is rendered through display list.

Should I put the set opacity function inside glNewList and glEndList?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, display lists are immutable, you can't change what's inside them. Setting the color before calling the display list should do the trick.